# Altium ring shaped pad

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, layout

i'm trying to create an airtight soldered mount for a pipe on a pcb depth sensor board I'm designing. To do this I am trying to create a custom pad in Altium that is a ring and is also plated. I've tried converting the ring to polygons, regions and cutouts. I've not been able to get any of them to become plated.[image]

The picture might make this easier to understand. I want to put a plated ring of some sort in the empty ring as seen above.

Comment: You can just copy your ring, and then paste it onto the solder paste layer (Change to paste layer, select Paste Special...On Current Layer).

Comment: Are your vias air tight?

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply place a full circle (p->u), set the thickness to your desired fitness and the solder mask to 0. The ring will be plated and no soldermask on top.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up just changing the solder mask expansion to "from rule" instead of "none" and verified that the ring was plated by viewing the gerber file.